# Music Practice Question (I think?)So I tried replicating notes of one piano to my piano, same notes, but it still sounds different - help?

Tags: digital-piano, production, mastering

I’m an amateur. I also have the sheet music stuff with me as well, and I have reference to the sound.

My attempt sounds about similar, but the original music seems a bit higher. I’ve copied the notes completely.

Here’s the original piece:

(I’m can’t seem to upload a file of my piece, apologies about that)

So uh, do I need to change my tempo or pitch or is it simply because of different pianos or…?

(Thank you for reading this question by the way ^^)

P.S: I don’t know if it makes a difference, but I’m doing it on a digital piano (a piano on an iPad).

Comment: The original piece is in tune, i.e. the pitches match the indicated keys. Do you have a transpose setting on your iPad accidentally set to +1 or something?

Comment: There’s no way to know without a reference but It could be that you’re playing it one octave lower.